# Unrecognized DB Format-Excel VBA to Access Database

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

Im using a .accdb file and connecting with the following code, which has worked for me multiple times, so I don't know why its corrupting the file this time.

```
dbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WaitAnalysisDB.accdb"
tblName = "Wait_Data_Table"
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & dbPath & "';"
conn.Open strcon
```

Does the "Unrecognized Format" Access error only occur due to an error in the connection string, or could it be my SQL statement inserting records as well? Thanks

Here's my code, if anyone cares to look through it. In the for loops that build the SQL statemetn (rcdDetail variable), I have an if statement, which basically says if there is a blank in Column A, then use the row above it that isnt blank.

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset, dbPath As String, tblName As String
Dim rngColHeads As Range, rngTblRcds As Range, colHead As String, rcdDetail As String
Dim ch As Integer, cl As Integer, notNull As Boolean, strcon As String, lr As Integer
Dim currentdate As String
Dim strdbcheck As String


'Code Checks if There Are Records for the Date in the DB
'If there is, then it skips the SQL code

currentdate = Date
dbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WaitAnalysisDB.accdb"
tblName = "Wait_Data_Table"
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & dbPath & "';"
conn.Open strcon

strdbcheck = "SELECT * FROM " & tblName
rs.Open strdbcheck, conn

rs.Filter = "Date= #" & currentdate & "#"
If Not rs.EOF Then
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    GoTo SkipExport
Else
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
        GoTo Export
End If



Export:

'Set Up Connections
dbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WaitAnalysisDB.accdb"
tblName = "Wait_Data_Table"

'Create Date Column
Worksheets("Wait Analysis DATA").Select
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
currentdate = Date: Range("O1").Value = "Date": Range(Range("O2"), Range("O" & lr)).Value = currentdate

Set rngColHeads = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("a1"), Range("a1").End(xlToRight))
Set rngTblRcds = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("K2:k" & lr).Offset(0, -10), Range("K2:k" & lr).Offset(0, 4))

'SQL connection String
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & dbPath & "';"

'Create String for Columns for SQL
colHead = "(["
For ch = 1 To rngColHeads.Count
    colHead = colHead & rngColHeads.Columns(ch).Value
    Select Case ch
        Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
            colHead = colHead & "])"
        Case Else
            colHead = colHead & "],["
    End Select
Next ch


On Error GoTo EndUpdate
conn.Open strcon
conn.BeginTrans

Dim tempcl As Integer

For cl = 1 To rngTblRcds.Rows.Count

    If Range("a2").Offset(cl - 1, 0) = "" Then
        tempcl = cl - Range("a2").Offset(cl, 0).End(xlUp).Rows.Count

        notNull = False
        rcdDetail = "('"
        For ch = 1 To rngColHeads.Count
        Select Case rngTblRcds.Rows(tempcl).Columns(ch).Value
            Case Is = Empty
                Select Case ch
                    Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
                        rcdDetail = Left(rcdDetail, Len(rcdDetail) - 1) & "NULL)"
                    Case Else
                        rcdDetail = Left(rcdDetail, Len(rcdDetail) - 1) & "NULL,'"
                End Select
            Case Else
                notNull = True
                Select Case ch
                    Case "11":
                        rcdDetail = rcdDetail & rngTblRcds.Rows(cl).Columns(ch).Value & "','"
                    Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
                        rcdDetail = rcdDetail & rngTblRcds.Rows(tempcl).Columns(ch).Value & "')"
                    Case Else
                        rcdDetail = rcdDetail & rngTblRcds.Rows(tempcl).Columns(ch).Value & "','"
                End Select
            End Select
    Next ch
        tempcl = 0
        GoTo skipads

    End If


    notNull = False
    rcdDetail = "('"
    For ch = 1 To rngColHeads.Count
        Select Case rngTblRcds.Rows(cl).Columns(ch).Value
            Case Is = Empty
                Select Case ch
                    Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
                        rcdDetail = Left(rcdDetail, Len(rcdDetail) - 1) & "NULL)"
                    Case Else
                        rcdDetail = Left(rcdDetail, Len(rcdDetail) - 1) & "NULL,'"
                End Select
            Case Else
                notNull = True
                Select Case ch
                    Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
                        rcdDetail = rcdDetail & rngTblRcds.Rows(cl).Columns(ch).Value & "')"
                    Case Else
                        rcdDetail = rcdDetail & rngTblRcds.Rows(cl).Columns(ch).Value & "','"
                End Select
            End Select
    Next ch

skipads:
    Select Case notNull
        Case Is = True
            rs.Open "INSERT INTO " & tblName & colHead & " VALUES " & rcdDetail, conn
        Case Is = False
                'do not insert record
    End Select


Next cl

EndUpdate:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        conn.RollbackTrans
        MsgBox "There was an error. This will exit the macro.", vbCritical, "Error!"
        End
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        conn.CommitTrans
    End If

    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0



SkipExport:
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Access database itself is fine - i.e. no corruption in the DB? I wouldn't be shocked if Access has had a, umm, hiccup.

Comment: Haha yeah Im almost 100% sure its the code, since I've deleted and recreated the table about 5 times now.

Comment: When does this error actually occur?

Comment: Rory It occurs whenever the code finishes and I try to open up the DB to look at it

Comment: Why do you have OERN before the `CommitTrans` and why are you using a `Recordset` for an Insert query rather than a `Connection.Execute`?

Comment: Honestly I found the code online, and it has worked for me in the past. I dont use it that much, so basically every time I need it, I just edit it a little to get it to do what I need

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `Conn.Execute "INSERT INTO " & tblName & colHead & " VALUES " & rcdDetail` instead of the `rs.Open ...` line?

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out, and let you know the results.

Comment: Didn't work. It wouldnt even insert into the Database

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok, here's what I'd try.

Manually type the path for dbPath, moreover the entire connection string. Perhaps path isn't being populated correctly.

Here's the connection string you can follow:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

If that doesn't work, double check your table name is correctly named. If it checks out, try wrapping your table name in []. So:

```
tblName = "[Wait_Data_Table]"
```

These are common things that give me grief, perhaps one of these are happening to you as well.